# Email template on Community registration merges field as blank

Tags: community, email-template

There's a custom community login page where the user logs using a custom field Document_Number__c on the contact related to the user.

So , when we send the welcome email we want to notify the user as if his/her username was the Document number (although internally it's still the normal username salesforce format).

I'm trying to adapt the Classic email template we're using but I don't seem to be able to show the information, everytime I get whatever I send after username as blank.

Adapted sample template:

```
Hello, {!Receiving_User.FirstName},

Welcome to  {!Community_Name}! To start press the following link: {!Community_Url}

Username: {!Receiving_User.CHC_fld_documentNumber__c}

Thanks,
{!Organization.Name}
```

I tried `{!Receiving_User.CHC_fld_documentNumber__c}` as per salesforce documentation ([doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337445&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1)) the fields referenced in this context are from the Contact, so in theory I assume(probably wrong) that I should be able to access that field.

The guest profile has acces to that field and to the contact object. I tried creating a Formula field, trying to get the values on User object. But none of that works but using `{!Receiving_User.username}` does. How can I show the document number?

Comment: Is `CHC_fld_documentNumber__c` the name of the field on `Contact`? If so, the `Receiving_User` is a `User` record. Use of a cross-object formula field is likely required since I doubt that `{!Receiving_User.Contact.CHC_fld_documentNumber__c}` will work (plus you would need to ensure the Contact was shared appropriately to the user).  Cross-object formula fields ignore sharing. However, the user must have permission to read `Contact` and the `CHC_fld_documentNumber__c` field.

Comment: That said, if you want to directly access the field through the "merged" User/Contact, make sure the Contact is shared with the User (e.g. create a Sharing Set so read access is granted where Contact:Id = User:ContactId) and that read permission is granted for Contact and the required field. (Assuming you don't have Public Read or Public Read/write sharing of Contact for external users.)

Comment: Account has private sharing settings, but there's a sharing rule to guest users to share Account the account their contact related to their user's in. Right now this is the one that's defined: 
User:Contact.RelatedAccount = Account:Id

Why would this one not work if Contact depends on parent and the User should have permission over the account?

Comment: You cannot create the sharing set on object contact since Visibility on contact still depends on parent. Doesn't even appear as an option in the list of sObjects.

Comment: That's absolutely true. Note, however, that Contact sharing via Account is a bad idea in many cases - it means that a given "community user" can in principle see details of both their own Contact and everyone else's Contacts when they share the same Account. It might be better to have external sharing of Contact as Private, then expose them with the Sharing Set as I previously suggested.

Comment: I agree, but the sharing settings of the org are not my call. And right now I have to just work with it. 
But I'm still puzzled as it seems even more weird that the user can't seem to access its own information while merging the template.